# Run codes exactly 10000 times each second

Tags: c++, linux, loops, timer

I'm writing test code for my program. I need code to run exactly 10000 times each second. my solution is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
  // do something here. Maybe ++k or some code else
  }
  usleep(1);
}
```

It turns out more time than 1 second. So I have to adjust 1000 and 100 to fit the requirement. It's not a good practice: when the running time changes, I have to change the code.

Any ideas?

Updates:

The program is working on Linux. I programmed a msg queue. As usual, it has producer and consumer. And I want to test throughout. I need the test code sends several msgs with little interval(100µs prefered).

If I send all the messages without sleep, the message queue will be full and not work for throughout testing.

Comment: *why* do you need to run code every 10ms? Either way you're probably going to be reliant on a timer running every 10ms.

Comment: It looks like 10/1ms, not 1/10ms to me.

Comment: @TheForestAndtheTrees An event that happens at 10,000 Hz has a period of merely 100 µs, not 10 ms. No idea how to achieve that reliably on non-realtime system.

Comment: @unwind - you're right, my mental maths didn't parse it right.

Comment: That code wouldn't guarantee that the inner loop will run **exactly** every 100µs. May be this is a XY problem?

Comment: But the requirement isn't "once every 100µs"; it's "10k times a second". So looping 10k times with a second-timer should be acceptable?

Comment: I agree with g-makulik: This seems like "I have this problem X, I think solution is Y, so I'll ask how to achieve Y". If you explain what you REALLY want to do, then we are more likely to give good advice.

Comment: The requirement (although impossible to guarantee under a non-real time OS) is not clear. Do you need to run something exactly every 100µs, or it's ok to just run it 10,000 times in the first part of a second and then take some free time until the next second comes?

Comment: @Daniel Daranas  the requirement is updated. :D   I need to run something exactly every 100µs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the requirement is "throttling" (that is "do not flood the message queue with messages", rather than "I want to send exactly one every X microseconds", then I would suggest a method like this:

1. Use a variable to store "last sent message" and "number sent since last pause".
2. If the "time between last sent message and now" is more than X microsconds, reset "number sent since last pause".
3. If number sent since last pause > Y, then sleep for A microseconds.

You may have to fiddle a bit with the X, Y and A parameters - make them constants, or even better "runtime configurable" via command line or a configuration file.

This should achieve the results you wish for, without slowing things down unnecessarily when you don't need to (e.g. you don't want to pause every 100 messages if you send one every second, right?), and it's a common patterns for all sorts of things (network packets, emails from automated email systems, etc, etc - just slightly different values of X, Y and A).

Comment: I would think it's better to allow "more, for longer" - e.g. 1000 per 100 us would give you better throughput.

Answer (score 5):

> It's not a good practice: when the running time changes, I have to change the code.

You're right, timing loops were never a good idea, and I haven't even heard of anyone writing them since the 1980s. There is far too much difference between high-end and low-end PCs today for this to be a viable strategy. Not to mention its fragility on a single multi-tasking machine.

You should use a timer instead. The APIs are platform-dependent, but you didn't tell us what your target platform is. Check your OS documentation for more details. There are probably several different types of timers to choose from, depending on the resolution you need.

Remember that even relatively high-resolution timers are not necessarily going to guarantee millisecond accuracy unless you're running on a real-time operating system.

Then there's the question of *why* you need to execute code on this interval. I imagine there's probably a better way of solving your problem, whatever it is. But there isn't enough information provided in the question to guess at that.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea, why would you need such test.

Anyway, you can use technique used in games, for getting stable FPS. For each frame, you measure calculation time, and then subtract it from desired value.

```
frame_time = 5ms
FPS = 50 -> 20ms/frame
sleep(20ms - 5ms)
```

But I'm afraid that for 10,000 loops per second, the calculation overhead will be too big, to fit 10k calculations in 1 second.